# Owners, groups, permissions for PHP & SSH access in AWS EC2

Tags: linux, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4

For a while now I have been searching the web for answers to the following, yet seem to be becoming more confused with the various answers to others' similar questions.

My environment:
AWS EC2 linux 2, apache 2.4, PHP 7.3, WinSCP (for SSH).
With AWS EC2 I have a choice of owners: root, www, ec2-user, apache
And a choice of groups: root, www, ec2-user, apache

Document root: www/html
Non-directory root which I classify as 'private' since I don't want browsers (except mine) to have access: www/private

I wish PHP to be able to create, edit and remove directories and files from both /html and /private. 
I also need WinSCP (my SSH) to be able to create, edit and remove directories and files in /html and /private (from the browser), and transfer files to both directories (from the browser), for development (not for world access).

Which owner:group should I give /html and its sub-directories?
Which owner:group should I give /private and its subdirectories?
Also, what would the directory and file permissions have to be in both cases?

Cheers